# ISO is only bootable by CD, not USB

Tags: boot, usb, iso-image, compact-disc, windows-pe

I have an ISO that I'm trying to get ready for PXE booting. After many attempts, I tried to check if it is even bootable by USB and it wasn't. Then I took a CD and burned the image onto it and it worked.

What reasons can there be for this?

Data concerning the image:
Symantec Antivirus Live CD, Windows PE 4.0, 396 MB size

Error message when booting (PXE & USB): 0xc0000017 (An unexpected error has occured) in Windows Boot Manager

If there's any more information I can supply please tell me so. I probably won't be able to upload the ISO itself due to licensing reasons (corporate disk).

Answer (score 2):

Copying the ISO or its contents to the USB doesn't make it bootable.

First make sure that your USB flash support booting.

Second you have to use a 3rd party software that allows to make your USB flash boot with your ISO file contents.

Comment: You may want to give some options for software, such as [Win32DiskImages](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention that: I tried it by using Unetbootin and the diskpart step-by-step manual from http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2012/07/26/create-bootable-usb-thumb-drive-key-using-diskpart-with-windows-8-media-to-install-windows-8-release-preview-or-other-operating-system.aspx - same result. I have also already booted other images from the stick successfully.